# Equality for functions in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

I recently stumbled on the following equality:

$$ \| (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + 1)^{1/2}g\|_{L^2} = \| g\|_{H^1}$$
for $g \in H^2(\mathbb{R})$. I tried to deduce the equality but failed (since I don't really have an idea how to attack this problem), and I also wasn't able to find a proof. If anyone would share a hint with me on how to approach, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\| (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +1)^{1/2} g\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \cdot (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +1) g \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g^2 + (\frac{d}{dx} g)^2 \, dx = \|g\|_{H^1}^2,$$
where we used integration by parts in the second to last step.

Comment: I'm not being able to grasp the integration by parts you used, This should be obvious but unfortunately, I am trying but I am stuck with the operator $\cdot (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +1)$ . hope someone can help me